# How can i make a thread "report back" to main thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Im making a app that monitors stuff on my computer, and i want to make it somewhat more difficult then just implementing a while loop.

So my question is how do i do it if i would like to fetch cpu load in a seperate thread, that updates a static variable in class

```
namespace threads
{
    class Program
    {
        static int cpuload = 0;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Thread th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(CheckCPULoad));
                th.Start();

                Thread.Sleep(1000); // sleep the main thread

                th.Abort();

                Console.WriteLine("load: {0}%", cpuload);
            }
        }

        static void CheckCPULoad()
        {
            // things are updated every 3 secs, dummy data
            Thread.Sleep(3000);

            Random rnd = new Random();
            cpuload++;// = rnd.Next(0, 100); // dummy data
        }
    }
}
```

As it is "load: 0%" is printed every time. what do i need to fix to make it show

```
load: 0% 
load: 0% 
load: 0%
```

?

thanks

Comment: Sending Windows messages is probably the easiest way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i get you right, this should solve your purpose. Notice the while loop inside the     `CheckCPULoad()` method.

```
class Program 
        {
            static int cpuload = 0;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(CheckCPULoad));
        th.Start();

        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("load: {0}%", cpuload);
        }
        th.Abort(); // Don't ever reach this line with while (true)        
    }

    static void CheckCPULoad()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            cpuload++;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: @Jason94, using sleep to wait for something is bad coding practice. You should really consider using events instead. And events are executed on separate threads.

Comment: +1 on using sleep to wait for something is bad coding practice. You should really consider using events instead. And events are executed on separate threads. – Mikael Svenson

Answer (score 3):

In order to "report back" to the main thread, the main thread has to be "listening". Which means, still running in a while loop and checking some kind of a queue for new items that represent the reports.

What you basically need is a queue where the worker thread will put its reports, and the main thread will periodically check this queue for reports from the worker.

You have two main approaches:

1. A blocking queue. Means that when
   there are no items the caller thread
   blocks until items arrive. This is
   good if the main thread has nothing
   to do except wait for items in the
   queue.
2. A non-blocking queue. Means that it
   returns immediately to the caller
   regardless of the items count. This
   is good if you want your main thread
   to be busy doing stuff and sometimes
   checking the queue for reports.

If your application is a UI application you automatically get the first approach, as this is how the UI works. To add "an item" you can use Control.BeginInvoke (in winforms) or Dispatcher.BeginInvoke (in wpf).

Answer (score 1):

The code you're using there starts the CheckCPULoad thread, waits 1 second and then aborts it. However, the first thing the CheckCPULoad thread does is to sleep for 3 seconds. So you never actually reach the `cpuload++` instruction. I suspect this would be closer to what you intended:

```
namespace threads
{
    class Program
    {
        static int cpuload = 0;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thread th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(CheckCPULoad));
            th.Start();

            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Console.WriteLine("load: {0}%", cpuload);
            }

            th.Abort(); // Don't ever reach this line with while (true)
        }

        static void CheckCPULoad()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
                cpuload++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *exact* same code?  Seriously?  Check that AutoResetEvent; its the way this should be done, anyhow.

Comment: Yes, exact same code. And I posted it first. Not that I'm bitter or anything ;) Anyway, I'm just pointing out the flaws in the logic as posted, didn't want to start a primer on Reactive Extensions or anything ...

Comment: Primer to Reactive Extensions added above :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a timer and events instead. This way you avoid your sleeping/busy waiting. Also consider using Interlocked.Increment as suggested if several threads can modify the static variable at the same time.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Timers;
using Timer = System.Timers.Timer;

namespace CpuLoad
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static int cpuload;
        private static readonly AutoResetEvent autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var timer = new Timer(3000);
            timer.Elapsed += CheckCPULoad;
            timer.Start();

            while (true)
            {
                autoEvent.WaitOne();
                autoEvent.Reset();
                Console.WriteLine(cpuload);
            }
        }

        private static void CheckCPULoad(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            cpuload++;
            autoEvent.Set();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `cpuload++` try using

```
Interlocked.Increment(ref cpuload);
```

Check - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd78zt0c.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The thread sleeps for 3 secs. You abort it after 1. Go figure :)

Answer (score 0):

With [callback](http://www.myelin.co.nz/notes/callbacks/cs-delegates.html) you can do that

here is an exsample:

```
public class Example2
{
    // Declaration - Take 1 parameter, return nothing
    public delegate void LogHandler(string message);

    // Instantiation - Create a function which takes delegate as one parameter
    // Verify if it is null before you use it
    public void Process(LogHandler logHandler)
    {
        if (logHandler != null)
        {
            logHandler("Process() begin");
        }

        if (logHandler != null)
        {
            logHandler("Process() end");
        }
    }
}

public class Example2DelegateConsumer
{
    // Create a method with the same signature as the delegate
    static void Logger(string s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Example2 ex2 = new Example2();

        // Invocation in the client
        Example2.LogHandler myLogger = new Example2.LogHandler(Logger);
        ex2.Process(myLogger);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to my original (plagiarised) answer below, this sort of situation where you're observing a set of values over time is a great fit for Reactive Extensions for .NET (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rxteam/). You can get the desired effect with Rx thus:

```
static void Main()
{
    var cpuLoadSequence = Observable.GenerateWithTime(
        0, // initial value
        i => true, // continue forever
        i => i + 1, // increment value
        i => i, // result = value
        i => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)); // delay 3 seconds

    using (cpuLoadSequence.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("load: {0}%", x)))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to stop.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```